# Как преобразовать трансляцию веб-камеры в фото

Tags: windows, изображения, visual-c++, видео, камера

Есть масса сайтов с веб-камерами, которые просто выводят видеоизображение на экран в браузере. Ну что-то типа [этого](http://tvway.ru/index.php?file=11596) или [этого](https://kirillovka.ks.ua/webcam-center-wide/).

Можно ли как-то на C/C++ получить, не открывая браузер и не эмулируя нажатия клавиш, просто картинку (jpg, скажем) с такой камеры в какой-то момент времени? Если да - то как это сделать проще всего?

Под Windows, VC++.

Comment: То есть средствами VC++ надо написать web-сервер, куда передавать, созданный теми же средствами загрузчик с web-камеры?

Comment: google chrome headless?

Comment: @Daemon-5 Нет! Снять с такой чужой камеры скриншот. Руками можно - открыть страницу, сделать копию экрана, вырезать нужную картинку. А как это же сделать программно, не открывая браузер и не делая ничего вручную?\

Comment: Понял. Что-нибудь вроде [Capture a screenshot from an online video stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940268/) не устраивает? Хотя там чтение потока производится сторонними утилитами, но решение вполне рабочее.

Comment: Например, для первого видео хватит команды: **ffmpeg -y -i http://95.215.176.83:8084/mjpg/video.mjpg?d=function -vframes 1 c:/output/1.jpg**

Comment: А если внимательно изучить содержимое сайта, то можно понять, что иногда не нужно анализировать поток. Так  как сайт сам выдаёт превьюшки. Соответственно, для второго сайта достаточно другой утилиты: **"wget --no-check-certificate -O c:/output/1.jpg https://edge01.kirillovka.ks.ua/preview/kirillovkawide.jpg"**. Получается, чтобы реализовать нужное решение, следует точно знать формат источника данных. Если не заморачиваться этим, то есть множество бесплатных онлайн-сервисов, которые делают скриншот удаленного сайта: проверка доступности, проверка дизайна, архивация и т.д.

Comment: @Daemon-5 Спасибо на наводку, буду смотреть в эту сторону.